# SQL Server - Best alternative to computed-columns when inserting multiple records?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with about 200 fields. More than half of those are calculated columns based on other computed columns based on another computed columns..... In addition the formula are very long. So I got of course the following error:

> Msg 1759, Level 16, State 0, Line 16
>    Computed column %s% in table %s% is not allowed to be used in another computed-column definition.

So I am a bit lost on what road to take. What is the best practice knowing that I am populating my table by inserting multiple records (very important). Should I use variables and cursors, should I use views?

```
INSERT INTO mainTable
SELECT * FROM #tempTable;
```

Comment: Well, unless the computed data is to change in the future, I guess you could look into database normalization and views.

Comment: I think you need to use VIEW or CTE as an alternative to computed-columns ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recomend using computed columns in tables only very sparingly.

The computation takes additional time when processing queries that trigger the computation (sometimes involuntarily). I would rather put most computations in views (or table value functions). That makes it much easier and clearer to see what the actual base data is (in the table) and what computed data is (in the view). You might even create diffrent views where each one only implements part of the computations based on the individual use case.

That would eliminate the negative effect on performance that the computation has on inserting large numbers of rows in the table.

However, when using Views for Computation, you will still have the issue, that you have to put the computation expressions in the views multiple times. You can not reference a column that is computed within a view from another column in the same view. One way around that are Common Table Expressions (CTE).

One exception to this recommendation are computed columns which are used frequently as criteria in queries. It would persist those computed columns in the table and index them. That can not be achieved with a view as easily.

Depending on your application's requirements and the performance impact of the computations, it might make sense to persist the views by indexing them. See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx) on Indexed Views for further details on this. You should thoroughly study the requirements of limitations of those before considering them.